# Magic "JFN8-1“ IC - IC Identification

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I've been searching for weeks now and haven't found an answer.

**Goal:**

Identification of this IC:

**JFN8-1 GA167003**

[image: Magic IC]

**What it does:**

If you press the button, it generates a "buzzing" sound to the 8 ohm 0.25 W speaker for 2 seconds. (Not longer even if you hold the button longer.)

It is driven by two 1.5V batteries in series = 3 V

If the button is pressed, 4 LEDs are turning on for 2 seconds as well.

**More information:**

I'm stunned that this one chip acts as a MCU, DAC and AMP all in one.
I thought it is maybe a low-powered (3V) 555 chip and the buzzing sound is generated through electricity like in this video:

https://youtube.com/shorts/ip5h3PaBz_4

But it wouldn’t stop after 2 seconds if I’m right. So that could only be part of the answer.

I know I could recreate this circuit with a MCU like RP2040 & AMP & DAC like the MAX98357, but that would be a couple of times more expensive. And a normal "piezo buzzer" doesn't have enough quality.

That's why I would like to know what this "magical" IC is and how somebody can recreate a cheap circuit like that. (Buzzer sound with real 0.25 W speaker & LEDs.)

Whole circuit:

[image: Whole Circuit]

Main board:

[image: Main Board]

LED board:

[image: LED Board]

0.25 W speaker:

[image: 0.25 W speaker]

Comment: It's probably an ASIC designed for toys. It may be mask programmed, in which case the part numbers could be specific to the customer and application. There are many such parts.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany is there a way to recreate such a cheap part on my own? Or do I need to go the MCU way?

Comment: Using an MCU would be easiest, but something like an RP2040 is a few orders of magnitude of overkill. An 8-bit PIC or ATtiny would even do the job blindfolded and with one hand tied behind its back.

Comment: There are MP3 modules aimed at hobbyists, last I looked. That might be a starting point.

Comment: Maybe somebody can recognize the company logo as starting point? And yes, it should be trivial to replicate the functionality with tiny MCU. Depending on which pins are used for power you may even get lucky and find MCU in a package that can be soldered to the existing pads. But you'd need at least an additional transistor and resistor for the speaker, since MCU won't be able to drive 0.25W directly.

Comment: @brhans thank you for your suggestion! Price wise a Pic18/Pic16 and ATtiny is more expensive or nearly identical to a RP2040 (1,03$) on JCLPCB. That’s why I tend to use it. The ESP32-S2 costs 1,17$ and does have a 8 bit DAC already built in. Of course I would like to have a cheaper solution, but at the moment I can’t find one.

Answer (score 0):

The company logo is [Matsushita](https://www.elnec.com/en/support/ic-logos/manufacturer-description/?manuf=Matsushita%20Panasonic), now Panasonic. As the comments suggest, it's probably an ASIC custom-made for this device and not manufactured elsewhere. Unless you can get another one of the original device (or something in a similar product line), there's no other way to get the original chip.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time! Do you have any suggestions how to rebuilt a circuit like that as cheap as possible?